# Is there a way to groupby multiple subsets of a single column in a Pandas dataframe without using a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a clever way to avoid looping through my subsets in order create different groupings on the same column? This is being asked in order to later help with parallelism.

```
import pandas as pd
types = ['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c','c','c','d']
values = [1,2,1,3,1,4,5,6,7,9,10]
day = [1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,3,2]

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(types,values,day),columns=['t','v','d'])

type_subsets = [['a','b'],
               ['a'],
               ['b','c','d']]

for s in type_subsets:
  df_subset = df[df['t'].isin(s)]
  print(s)
  print(df_subset.groupby('d')['v'].sum())
```

This currently has an output, but I was wondering if there is a way to represent this in a single dataframe?

```
['a', 'b']
d
1    6
2    2
Name: v, dtype: int64
['a']
d
1    3
2    1
Name: v, dtype: int64
['b', 'c', 'd']
d
1    12
2    16
3     7
Name: v, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
pd.DataFrame(type_subsets).apply(
    lambda row:
    df[df.t.isin(row)].groupby('d')['v'].sum(),
    axis=1))
```

which will give you:

```
d     1     2    3
0   6.0   2.0  NaN
1   3.0   1.0  NaN
2  12.0  16.0  7.0
```

You had `6` and `2` in your first output from for loop: those are in the first line here.
Your second output, `3` & `1`, are in the second line.
Your last output: `12`, `16`, `7`: my last line.

So we "represent" the same data, without a `for` loop.

---

Breakdown of what's going on:

`pd.DataFrame(type_subsets)` is:

```
   0     1     2
0  a     b  None
1  a  None  None
2  b     c     d
```

with `apply(,axis=1)`, we apply the function to each row. To avoid having to define a function separately, we use a lambda function. `lambda row:`, so input is each row. Then: `df[df.t.isin(row)].groupby('d')['v'].sum()`. This is the same operation you have performed within the for loop.

Comment: Hope this is understandable, let me know if there are unclear parts.

Comment: It is clear, but haven't had a chance to try it but it yet. Any idea if this is more/less efficient than the loop technique?

Comment: Haven't timed it, but looping usually is a bad idea when it comes to dataframes, so probably this is better.